# Trying to pass in values from an env variable group to terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, yaml, environment-variables

so I've been at this for a couple hours now at least. I've tried passing in two variables using the TF_VAR prefix. I've verified the pipeline is importing the var groups correctly in the logs. I'm thoroughly stumped and could really use some help haha.

references -
[How to pass Variables with Secrets (User, Password) in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69378722/how-to-pass-variables-with-secrets-user-password-in-terraform)

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

[main tf infra file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pcLU.png)

[tfvars file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbH4o.png)

[Environmental variable group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb4iY.png)

[AzDO yaml pipeline snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9U8E.png)

Steps -

1. I used the links below as references.
2. I tried setting the var values in clear text in the tfvars file for kicks, which is a big no-no, but just to see if it'd take.
3. I also tried exporting the environment variables using export TF_VAR_variable_name as a different way to do this.
   In each attempt the pipeline stalls and doesn't do anything making me think the values are never getting to the variables for some reason. My current params and run cmd opts included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DevOps secret variables, they won’t get mapped to environment variables for security reasons. You have to pass them as variables.

1. Declare variables in your tfvar file as shown below. Refer to them using `var.admin_password` and `var.admin_user` in `main.tf`.

```
variable "admin_password" {
  type = string
}
variable "admin_user" {
  type = string
}
```

2. Pass the value of `admin_password` and `admin_user` to the terraform task using `-var` argument.

```
- task:TerraformTaskV3@3
  displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
  inputs:
    command: 'plan'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    environmentServiceName: '<service_connection_name>'
    commandOptions:' -input=false -var "admin_password=$(TF_VAR_admin_password)" -var "admin_user=$(TF_VAR_admin_user)" '
```

Comment: thank you so much! It worked like a charm, I was going nuts haha.